# Yocto packagegroup install

Tags: installation, yocto, recipe

I have multiple recipes, I want to group them inside a packagegroup to make the install easier of these recipes in the image.

I have create the following file : `sources/meta-test/recipes-lib/packagegroups/packagegroup-lib.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "Libraries package group"
LICENCE = "CLOSED"
SUMMARY = "Package group of all libraries recipes"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"

inherit packagegroup

RDEPENDS_{PN} = " \
    exception \
    logger \
"
```

And then in my build/conf/local.conf, I install my packagegroup :
`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-lib"`

```
bitbake -c cleansstate packagegroup-lib
bitbake -c clean fsl-image-machine-test
bitbake packagegroup-lib
bitbake fsl-image-machine-test
```

I flash the image but I can't find the installed packages (of the packagegroup) once I boot the image. In the tmp folder, I can find the librairy at the right place :
`./tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa7hf-neon/logger/usr/lib/libLogger.so`

Comment: Honestly, it looks fine. The only thing I see is the use of IMAGE_INSTALL in conf/local.conf. Can you try with CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL instead and see if that fixes it? You anyway most likely need to add this package to an image recipe somehow. You can use bbappend on image recipes as well, so create one for fsl-image-machine-test and add your IMAGE_INSTALL there (or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL). Put as few things as possible in conf/local.conf.

Comment: A thought, does the package called "logger" contain the lib? Sometimes the package will automatically be renamed to e.g. liblogger* if it only contain a shared library. Inspect the packages-split directory to see what files end up in which packages, look in tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon/logger/<your version>/packages-split/.

Comment: @qschulz I try to make the `IMAGE_INSTALL` inside the recipe of the packagegroup (and later with CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL). I end up with the same result

Comment: @ErikBotö the library seems at the correct position in `packages-split` folder

Comment: @bacara, IMAGE_INSTALL has to be added to the *image* recipe (in that case fsl-image-machine-test.bb or in a bbappend for this image recipe) and not a "normal recipe" (which creates packages). As the variable name tells us, this is for installing packages in an *image*, so its place is in an *image* recipe.
Please have a look at @ ErikBotö suggested answer, I'm pretty sure he correctly spot the mistake made in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small typo that I didn't spot until I tried your packagegroup-lib.bb recipe here locally, and noticed that RDEPENDS line didn't work. It doesn't fail during parsing, but RDEPENDS is not set correctly.

It says `RDEPENDS_{PN}` but it should say `RDEPENDS_${PN}`.

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you. I'm always confused by bitbake when there's an issue like this, and it doesn't tell me what's wrong.